# How do I show all tasks assigned to a user on one Jira board?

Tags: jira

The current issue we're having is we have several Jira boards/projects for different parts of our company. One of our users is in one board that is a Scrum board and one board that is Kanban. I tried creating a boarding to pull in all of this agent's tasks, but it will only  show the agile board OR the Kanban board (depending on which on I choose the new board to be) not both at the same time. The agent wishes to see all of their tasks on one board, and see what tasks are WIP, Done, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should work:

Issues->Search for Issues->JQL="Assignee = [user]"->Save as

Manage Boards->Create Board->Kanban->Existing Filter->select the filter you created